# React rendering Array.map data twice

Tags: reactjs, typescript, dictionary, double, rendering

I have a small piece of react code which renders a list of names and their related information like age and email addresses. The code compiles fine but I see that the data is rendered twice on the page. Here is how I call the component:

```
const peopleData : Person[] = [{id:1,name:"John",age:22},{id:2,name:"Sasha",age:23}]

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <Basic {...peopleData}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is the component:

```
export interface Person {
    id      : number;
    name    : string;
    age     : number;
    email?  : string;
}


function Basic(input: Person[]) {
  let newPeopleData : Person[] = [];
  const [data,setData] = useState<Person[]>([]);

  useEffect(()=>{
    // Create a new data array 
    let data : Person[] = Object.values(input);
    let size : number = Object.values(input).length;

    console.log("Data load start." + JSON.stringify(data));
    for(let index=0;index<size;index++)
    {
        let {id,name,email} = input[index] as Person;
        let newEmail = name + "@gmail.com"
        newPeopleData.push({id:id,name:name,email:newEmail} as Person)
    }
    setData(newPeopleData);
    console.log("Data loaded." + JSON.stringify(data));
    return ()=>{
        console.log("Data deleted." + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  },[]);


  return (
    <div>
        {data.map((unit)=>{
            return (
                <h1 key={unit.id}>{unit.name},age:{unit.age},email:{unit.email}</h1>
            )
        })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Is the "peopleData" array passed correctly to the component? Or is there a better recommended way to do it?
2. Why does the browser render the data twice when it is refreshed, although the "unit.id" is unique for each dataset.

Thanks

I tried to remove the key attribute inside the h1 tag thinking that React can assign its own unique IDs to each map object. But this did not work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. React use props, the correct this:

```
<Basic data={peopleData}/>
```

in the Component:

```
interface Props {
  data: Person[]
}
function Basic({data}: Props) {}
```

2. in the console data render twice because react in the index use the Strict Mode

```
<React.StrictMode>
```

Comment: personally i prefer passing props like this:

`<Basic peopleData={peopleData} />`


that way i dont have to remember what this data is inside the child.

Comment: That's great feedback. Thanks.  They key was in making the interface like this :   <br/> 
 `export interface BasicProps {
  data : Person[];
}`   instead of doing this : ` export interface BasicProps {
  data : Person;
}<br/>
*And then making an array of interface like this  *<br/>
function Basic(props: BasicProps[])  `

Answer (score 1):

move the array variable inside useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {

  // move the variable inside as useEffect runs twice in dev strict mode
  // to render it once
  // The main issue: the useEffect needs to be passed 
  // dependency array useEffect(() => {}, [input])
  // rendering twice in dev mode helps to catch cleanup errors

  let newPeopleData : Person[] = [];

  // Create a new data array 
  let data : Person[] = Object.values(input);
  let size : number = Object.values(input).length;

  console.log("Data load start." + JSON.stringify(data));
  for(let index=0;index<size;index++)
  {
      let {id,name,email} = input[index] as Person;
      let newEmail = name + "@gmail.com"
      newPeopleData.push({id:id,name:name,email:newEmail} as Person)
  }
  setData(newPeopleData);
  console.log("Data loaded." + JSON.stringify(data));
  return ()=>{
      console.log("Data deleted." + JSON.stringify(data));
  }
},[]); // pass dependency
```

Comment: Hi. The props passing is shown in the first code block in my post. Have a look.

Comment: What I ment id, passing an array to a component is not ideal, since you wont be able to pass other props easily,  their new docs are really helpful 
https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/thinking-in-react
and hope the answer helpful

Comment: Hi Azzy. Thank you for replying. Your point about moving the array inside helped.  I think what happens is that the strict mode was persisting the last content of the array and additional data was being pushed into it when the component mounted the second time.  Placing the array declaration inside the effect deletes it from memory once the effect has finished running and makes it empty the next time for the strict mode. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Welcome, glad it helped, you got it
in strict mode its  setup → cleanup → setup  https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/react/useEffect#my-effect-runs-twice-when-the-component-mounts
To understand more: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/lifecycle-of-reactive-effects#the-lifecycle-of-an-effect
if the answer helped,  upvoting or marking it as answerd will be appricaited